# Блокировка с задержкой

Tags: c#

День добрый, требуется заблокировать textbox`s на минуту, а потом снять блокировку, и если были введены неверные значения более двух раз. Если в третий раз опять ошибка, то + еще 2 минуты, и т.д.
Я пробую следующим образом, но таймер задерживается навсегда:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Start();
            textBox3.Enabled = false;
            textBox4.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Interval+=1000;
            if (timer1.Interval == 15000)
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                textBox3.Enabled = true;
                textBox4.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь попробовать так. Не самый лучший способ, но вроде как работает.

В глобальные переменные:

```
int K = 0;
DateTime ed;
```

На кнопку

```
if (textBox2.Text != "testwork" && textBox2.Enabled)
{
    K++;
    if (K > 3) 
    { 
      ed = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((K + 1) * 60); 
      textBox2.Enabled = false; 
      timer1.Start(); 
    }
    else if (K > 2) 
    { 
      ed = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds((K - 1) * 60); 
      textBox2.Enabled = false; 
      timer1.Start(); 
    }
    else if (K == 2) 
    { 
      ed = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60); 
      textBox2.Enabled = false; 
      timer1.Start(); 
    }
    else MessageBox.Show("Вы ввели неверное значение.");
}
else { MessageBox.Show("Good"); K = 0; }
```

На таймер:

```
if (DateTime.Now > ed) { textBox2.Enabled = true; timer1.Stop(); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно пойти слегка другим путем.

Определить свой текстбокс, который будет сам хранить количество ошибок

```
public class MyAwesomeTextbox : TextBox
{
    public int ErrorInputCount {get;set;}   
}
```

При обновлении текста в текстбоксе, смотреть на количество ошибок и в зависимости от этого блочить или не блочить текстбокс

```
private async void Tb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tb = sender as MyAwesomeTextbox;

    if (tb.Text != "123")
    {
        tb.IsEnabled = false;
        tb.ErrorInputCount++;           
        switch(tb.ErrorInputCount)
        {
            case 1: // 1 ошибка - ничего страшного
                break;
            case 2: // 2 ошибки - блочим на секунду
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                break;
            case 3: // 3 ошибки - блочим на 2 секунды
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                break;
            default: // более 3 ошибок - 3 секунды
                await Task.Delay(3000);
                break;
        }
        tb.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        tb.ErrorInputCount = 0; // ввод верный, сброс счетчика ошибок
    }
}
```

Преимущества:

1. никакого доп состояния на форме\окне
2. отсутствие таймеров, код так немного почище
3. один обработчик можно использовать для любого количества текстбоксов